# Is it advisable to use custom font in an iOS application?

Tags: ios, fonts

I am a UI designer and starting with iOS app design, I want to know is it advisable to use other fonts rather than system fonts i.e SF Pro/Text

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and you shouldn't do it again. But to answer your question: Yes of course.

Comment: Why not? Also Try to design with iOS Components (ie, tabbar instead menu. Segmented index instead of Swipable tabs) etc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because User asking for design related question

Comment: This  question is fine here. It's about designing an iOS app. That's part of programming.

Answer (score 2):

Using other fonts in your application is perfectly acceptable. Being a designer you are probably well aware of when custom font use is a good idea and when it's simply gaudy. But if you have legitimate reasons to use different fonts, they are fine. The system fully supports adding custom fonts to applications as the designers of the system expected that apps would need and use that functionality. (See for example the [UIFont](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont) class.)